# Screen recording/capturing with gstreamer or any other frame work that works with eglfs

Tags: qt, gstreamer-1.0

I am facing a problem in recording my screen. I was able to record screen with Nvidia jetson tx2 easily with ximagesrc plugin in gstreamer but without x11 it is using eglfs_kms_egldevice integration to run qt window which i am not able to capture. I tried to capture fb0 with ffmpeg but it was able to capture the console and not the qt application window running over it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `eglfs` does not write to `/dev/fb0`, so capturing from there will show whatever is "behind" the Qt app. eglfs uses the GPU, so is going via `/dev/dri/card0` and friends instead. From my research you have three options:

1. Capture from the DRI/DRM/KMS pipe. `ffmpeg` has the `kmsgrab` input device to do just that. The simplest solution is `ffmpeg -f kmsgrab -i - -vf 'hwdownload,format=bgr0' output.mp4`. Unfortunately the content may be garbled.
2. Redirect Qt to the framebuffer. Turns out this will do: `./my_app -platform linuxfb:fb=/dev/fb0`. You can then use the more user-friendly  `ffmpeg -f fbdev -i /dev/fb0 output.mp4` to record the screen. Unfortunately this will not render any features that use the GPU, such as some effects, animations and other multimedia.
3. Finally you can ask the app use the VNC platform (`-platform vnc`), use a VNC client on another device, and record the session there. Back in Qt 4.8 you could even specify VNC **and** [another driver](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt-embedded-displaymanagement.html#subdrivers-and-multiple-drivers) at the same time. Unfortunately I don't think that's [possible any more](https://forum.qt.io/topic/75946/how-to-use-eglfs-and-vnc-plugin-at-the-same-time-in-qt-5-8), so this is not a great solution if you still need a local display for whatever reason.

So a few solutions, none of them ideal.